# Force Carbonating and Serving Kegs Simulanteously

Tags: kegging, force-carbonation

I'm trying to come up with the most cost effective way to have kegs both force carbonating at 20+ PSI and (other) kegs being served at 10-12 PSI. Obviously, I could buy an entirely separate regulator and CO2 tank, but that can be quite expensive.

So far my only other idea has been to attach a manifold to a regulator on a CO2 tank and attach a second regulator to the outlet of that manifold. I'd then attach a second manifold to the second regulator. The first regulator would be run at force carbonation pressures while the second would be run at serving pressures. This all seems a bit Rube Goldberg-esque but I'm curious if anyone's either tried this with success or has a more practical idea.

Comment: A thing like that http://www.kegkits.com/Regulators/2PressureRegulator_14_B.jpg solves your problem? Take a look at this link with some regulator variations: http://www.kegkits.com/CorrectRegulator.htm

Comment: Accepting Franklin Combs answer but this is also an effective solution. I should have had the foresight to just buy a double regulator from the beginning.

Comment: Nice answer! Go ahead and make it. Good luck! (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely don't need a second tank. What you need is something like [this](http://www.compactappliance.com/tap-rite-two-product-dual-pressure-beer-regulator/T752HP.html?cgid=Wine_and_Beverage-Kegerators-Beer_Regulators).

If you have an existing dual-gauge regulator you can just remove the [cylinder stem](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/brewing/kegging/gas-hardware/regulators/cylinder-valve-stem-rht.html) and use a [nipple](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/brewing/kegging/gas-hardware/regulators/regulator-coupler-1-4-npt-hex-left-hand-thread.html) to couple a single-gauge regulator on there. Or if you have a single-gauge regulator you'd just remove the cap nut from where the second (high-pressure) gauge would be and do the same kind of thing.

What you have to look out for is the thread directions on these different fittings. Some have all right-threaded parts. Some have a mix of right-and-left threads. Some have all left-threads. Make double sure you're getting the right threads, and also note the threads before taking anything apart, as you may be tightening something you thought you were loosening.

You'll want to make sure your attaching regulators via the port labeled 'HI' or 'HIGH' on the back so your second regulator is getting full pressure from the tank, not stepped down pressure from the first regulator.

And don't forget to use a couple wraps of [teflon tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_seal_tape) when making threaded unions.

This will give you two (or I guess as many as you wanted) regulators drawing from one tank with fully independent pressure control, easy peasy.

Comment: Ah, thanks! This is much less convoluted than what I was conjuring up. I think I will go ahead and just port over my existing dual-gauge regulator.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help